# find a level set $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ of infinite cardinalty when $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Suppose $U=\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ for some compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $f:U\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on $U$.

**Question.**  Under what conditions can we find some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(u)=\alpha$ for infinitely many $u\in U$?  In other words, I am trying to find *any* level set of infinite cardinality.

**Discussion.**

If $K$ is a set of isolated points then $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and we get an $\alpha$ via the meromorphic version of Picard's Great Theorem.

On the other hand, an $\alpha$ does not always exist.  For instance, if $f(u)=u$ then obviously there is no such $\alpha$.  To eliminate this kind of trivial counter-example, we could require that $f$ be a non-polynomial.

What additional conditions could we impose on $K$ and $f$ to guarantee the existence of a level set $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ of infinite cardinality?  Perhaps it is enough for $f$ to have no analytic continuation beyond $U$.

**Motivation.**

This question is actually motivated by a problem in functional analysis.  I have a Banach space $X$, a continuous linear operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$, and a vector $x\in X$ such that the set $(T^nx)_{n=0}^\infty$ is linearly independent.  I need a nonzero functional $x^*\in X^*$ such that the holomorphic map $u\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(T)\mapsto x^*((u-T)^{-1}x)$ admits a level set of infinite cardinality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, then the existence of such an $\alpha$ will follow now from Picard's Great Theorem again.

In general however, we have counter-examples. Construct an injective function on $U=\mathbb{C} \setminus   \overline { \mathbb{D}}$ as follows: Since $\dfrac{1}{z}$ maps $U$ to $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$ injectively, you can now compose it with your favourite random injective function on $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$.

In the non-compact case, let $U=\mathbb{C}  \setminus (-\infty,0]$. $f(z)=\ln(z)$ defines a non-polynomial function on $U$ which is $1$-$1$, thus admitting no level set of infinite cardinality.

Comment: As I understand it, Picard's Great Theorem is stated for meromorphic functions and entire functions.  But $K$ might be, for instance, the closed unit disk, and $f$ might have no analytic continuation beyond $U$.  In such a case, the conditions of Picard are not satisfied---at least, as it appears on wikipedia.  Is there a version of Picard which covers the general case?

Comment: @BenWallis, please see my edit.

Comment: Your answer is correct if $K$ is empty. But for nonempty $K$ you have to exclude much more than just polynomial mappings. For instance, you can have injective holomorphic maps $f: U\to U$ which are not linear-fractional.

Comment: @studiosus, I think now I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the holomorphic functions I'm working with all have the form $z\mapsto x^*((z-T)^*x)$, and each of these has a removable singularity at infinity by virtue of the Neumann series.  So, I guess I'm out of luck.